# Checking lazy loaded properties have been instantiated

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

In a class which has a lazy loaded property, such as:

```
private Collection<int> someInts;

public Collection<int> SomeInts
{
    get
    {
        if (this.someInts == null) this.someInts = new Collection<int>();
        return this.someInts;
    }
}
```

Is it worth also having a property such as:

```
public bool SomeIntsExist
{
    get { return (this.someInts != null && this.someInts.Count > 0); }
}
```

And then using that property.. eg:

```
if (thatClass.SomeIntsExist)
{
    // do something with thatClass.SomeInts collection
}
```

or is this premature optimisation.  Its certainly easier to roll with something like below, but it will instantiate the collection needlessly:

```
if (thatClass.SomeInts.Count > 0)
{
    // do something with thatClass.SomeInts collection
}
```

Is the compiler smart enough to figure things like this out?  Is there a better way?

Comment: By the way, your code is not thread safe. Multiple threads may at the same time find that the backing field is null and each create an empty collection. In consequence subsequent code may use the collection created by thread A for some time until thread B overwrites it with an empty collection again. You have to use some form of locking if you need thread safety.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks - good comment. I am aware of those issues, but tried to keep the example simple :).

Comment: @Daniel "By the way, your code is not thread safe". Instance members of most Framework classes are not thread safe, so this is nothing unusual. In fact I'd say it's generally best practice to leave thread safety to users of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even lazy initialization of a property sounds like premature optimization. There are only very few cases I can think of where delaying the creation of an empty collection helps to solve a problem (assuming your example is not oversimplified).

But when you have to delay the collection initialization then you probably should (or even have to) optimize the `Exists` method, too, because lazy initialization is a critical requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is worth having properties like this if you are dealing with expensive data retrieval e.g. database queries.

However, there is a flaw in your code. `SomeIntsExist` will only ever really give you the correct answer if the property has been accessed beforehand, if the property is lazy loaded then there may indeed be integers but they just haven't been loaded yet. It should be renamed to something like `IsInitialised`. I know it's an example but it's probably still worth pointing out :)

Comment: I didnt follow your 2nd paragraph. The SomeIntsExist property will return true only if the collection has been instantiated and has items, correct? I guess you mean if it was accessed by multiple threads it could be an issue?

Comment: @Paul: I was assuming that you would be loading your list (as you did mention lazy loaded property) when you accessed it. However, looking at your code again you are lazy initializing the property which in this particular scenario will gain you no advantages unless you explicitly need to check that the property has been initialized.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and apologies for my confusing terminology!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not figure things like that out automatically.
That means, in the last case

```
if (thatClass.SomeInts.Count > 0) 
{ 
    // do something with thatClass.SomeInts collection 
}
```

the collection will be instantiated.

So in my opinion it depends on how expensive it is to initialize the collection - in the simple case, it is not really expensive, but the wasted memory might sum up...

Answer (score 0):

if the lazy loaded class is a big one and the initialization would take some time.... such a boolean make sence.

bin in case of a simple .net collection it doesnt make sence in my opinion.